# Error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null(…)) pop out whenever placeAt() method is called

Tags: javascript, dojo

The following codes works fine in my other project but it keep pop out this error when i placing a object to div in current project. is there any concern must be aware for placeAt() method?

```
rest.then(function(response){
                var dataset = response.data;
                array.forEach(dataset, function(single, i){
                    if(dataset[i].favorite){
                        favorite++;
                    }

                    if(dataset[i].status == "OO"){
                        outOfService++;
                    }
                });

                try{
                    var dashBoardShortCutCell = new DashBoardShortCutCell();
                    dashBoardShortCutCell.construct("favorite", favorite);
                    dashBoardShortCutCell.placeAt(context.shortCutContainerNode);
                }catch(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }

                dashBoardShortCutCell = new DashBoardShortCutCell();
                dashBoardShortCutCell.construct("Out of Service", outOfService);

                try{

                    dashBoardShortCutCell.placeAt(context.shortCutContainerNode);
                }catch(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }

            }, function(err){
                console.log("Error", err);
            }, function(evt){

            });
```

the console is then displaying :

DashboardPage.js:85 TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null(…)

DashboardPage.js:95 TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null(…)

Comment: This question seems unanswerable due to a lack of sufficient context (or, preferably, a sufficient reduction of the problem to an isolated, reproducible test case).  I see nothing in the provided code that would be referencing anything's `style` property (though I have no way of knowing what `DashBoardShortCutCell` does).  Moreover, does this question obsolete your [earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551387/procedure-skipped-after-placeat-method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cannot read property 'style' of null"

From the error itself already mentioned the root cause. Your JavaScript is trying to do some styling to undefined/null node. Please make sure you defined properly the target node